# How to escape blade tags in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm working on a small CRM system where users need the option to send emails to other users and to load predefined templates. Currently the templates are stored in my views/emails/templates folder. Example: new_order.blade.php

Inside the template I have the following code syntax:

```
Visit us at: {{{ (isset($isTemplate) && $isTemplate) ? '{{ $offerUrl }}' : $offerUrl }}}
```

This kind of works but parses the string that need to be outputed exactly like that to real php code.

```
Visit us at: <?php echo $offerUrl ?>
```

Is there any solution to echo blade tags?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `@{{` to escape a blade syntax. So you could use

```
'@{{ $offerUrl }}'
```

Answer (score 1):

That @{{ $offerUrl }} syntax works only if both(open and close) curly bracket pairs exist. Otherwise if string contains any curly bracket I suggest to use plane old php syntax like

```
<?php echo '$offerUrl }}'?>
```

and you will have nothing weird to ecape.